# Why do people still use things like \^{} rather than \symbol{94}?

Tags: characters

Why do people still use things like `\^{}` rather than `\symbol{94}` when the latter gives you the actual ASCII character while the former just gives you something which LaTeX considers a lookalike? Perhaps I'm very unusual in having a use case where it matters.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  not all fonts are defined in terms of unicode, and some publishers' document classes don't easily accommodate fonts that are constructed that way.  also, it's easier for some people to remember shapes than numeric values.

Comment: "Where it matters" you might well want to express your intent otherwise, but if it matters that much, then you should probably be using \capitalcircumflex{}. There is certainly no guarantee that \symbol{94} will give you a circumflex in every font file: neither \^{} nor \symbol{94} nor \capitalcircumflex "gives you" an ASCII circumflex *character*: they just create a mapping in the PDF which *in most Latin-based text fonts* causes a glyph resembling a circumflex to be drawn. I suspect a lot of people would use \verb+^+ to make it clear it's the glyph they're interested in, not its meaning.

Comment: Personally, I wasn't aware that something such as `\symbol{94}` existed. Using `\^{}` seems more flexible/ generic to me, rather than learning hundreds of specific codes.

Comment: @PeterFlynn,  @barbara-beeton, that's exactly my point. I'm forced to use a legacy customized font which has assigned a totally different character to \x5e/ASCII 94 than the one I get if I put `\^{}` in my code, and I need both with a distinction between them. It seems like `\system` is the right way to get them; but you are saying that it gives the character at codepoint *n* in whatever encoding the fonts happens to be made for, and not Unicode character *n*? I always use XeLaTeX so I didn't think much about the font dinosaurs out there. Are ppl still using them, apart from symbol fonts?

Comment: Maybe what I actually should use is `\string` but that seems to me to be even scarier.

Comment: @bpj I believe that is what happens but I wouldn't guarantee that I have understood all the ramifications. I would think there are very large numbers of people still using latex or pdflatex with Type 1 Postscript fonts, simply because once you have set them up, they work, and you might not want to re-buy them in OTF/TTF format. They should of course also work with XeLaTeX but I'm still testing this.

Comment: Sure Type 1 fonts work fine with XeLaTeX at least on *nix. I haven't TeXed on Windows in ages so I don't remember if they work there to. That would depend on the system rather than on XeTeX anyway I guess.

Comment: @PeterFlynn I just realized that the results I'm getting indicate what's happening. That `\^{}` gave me a visible character at all was because the font I was using was grafted on top of CP1252 in in the first place, and apparently XeTeX could equate that character with U+02C6 MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX. Apparently it is some mapping between PostScript/Adobe names and Unicode which the font/font engine does, or I'd probably have gotten a square box.

Comment: @PeterFlynn BTW where is `\capitalcircumflex` defined? I wasn't aware of it and tried to look up its definition but `texdoc` didn't know of it.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I should have said: it's in textcomp,sty I think. Or perhaps in one of the encoding files.

Comment: I just noted that I made a typo in my comment of Apr 3 at 21:24: "`\system`" should be `\symbol` of course!